# Python/Threading/Barrier: Is this a correct usage of Barrier?

Tags: python, multithreading

Perhaps i have not understood the barrier concept of threading. But i wrote a code that i want to learn it is a correct usage of barrier or not.

Here are the codes:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import time
import random
import threading


def f(b):
    time.sleep(random.randint(2, 10))
    print("{} passed the barrier at: {}".format(threading.current_thread().getName(), time.ctime()))
    b.wait()


barrier = threading.Barrier(3)
for i in range(3):
    t = threading.Thread(target=f, args=(barrier,))
    t.start()
```

Comment: That code doesn't test the barrier... try prints before and after the wait.

Comment: So, should i write `time.sleep(random.randint(2, 10))` and the `print()` statement after the wait?

Comment: Yes, you just want to see the difference in return from sleep and return from wait. See my answer.

Comment: Ok. I got it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The barrier sets up a count of threads that will wait together until that count is reached. With a small change in the test

```
import time
import random
import threading

def f(b):
    time.sleep(random.randint(2, 10))
    print("{} woke at: {}".format(threading.current_thread().getName(), time.ctime()))
    b.wait()
    print("{} passed the barrier at: {}".format(threading.current_thread().getName(), time.ctime()))

barrier = threading.Barrier(3)
for i in range(3):
    t = threading.Thread(target=f, args=(barrier,))
    t.start()
```

You can see that all threads wake from sleep at different times but return from `wait` at the same time.

```
$ python3 o.py
Thread-2 woke at: Sun May 20 11:59:16 2018
Thread-3 woke at: Sun May 20 11:59:21 2018
Thread-1 woke at: Sun May 20 11:59:22 2018
Thread-1 passed the barrier at: Sun May 20 11:59:22 2018
Thread-2 passed the barrier at: Sun May 20 11:59:22 2018
Thread-3 passed the barrier at: Sun May 20 11:59:22 2018
```